# ReactBoostrap Declaration or statement expected. TS1128

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, react-typescript

when adding the button in my react app. When showing this type of error i cann't understand.

**TypeScript error in /media/XXPath1/XXPath2/React-Wrokspace/resto/node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/index.d.ts(2,1):
Declaration or statement expected.  TS1128**

```
    1 | export { default as Accordion } from './Accordion';
  > 2 | export type { AccordionProps } from './Accordion';
      | ^
    3 | export { default as AccordionContext } from './AccordionContext';
    4 | export { default as AccordionCollapse } from './AccordionCollapse';
    5 | export type { AccordionCollapseProps } from './AccordionCollapse';
```

---

**Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class RestaurantList extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>RestaurantList</h1>
                <Button variant="primary">Submit</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default RestaurantList;
```

---

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "resto",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.53",
    "@types/react-bootstrap": "^0.32.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.6",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "json-server": "^0.16.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.4",
    "reactstrap": "^8.6.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for a minute wondering what was going on until I checked my package.json file and saw that version was only `3.7.5` though my editor was using `3.9.X`. Upgrading the version fixed the issue.
Try this `npm install -g typescript@latest`. You can also use this command      `npm update` instead of install, without the latest modifier.